# EPiServer 8 shared VPP folder

Tags: c#, tfs, episerver

i want to configure multi-developer development environment for a web site in EPi server 8. i have followed this [article](http://talk.alfnilsson.se/2013/06/24/versioning-add-ons-in-episerver-7/) to do this(i guess that's the only article provided on web for this purpose :-) )

i have moved my EPi Server database and VPP folder(Modules/_protected) to a shared location

I have changed following physical paths web.config

```
<episerver.packaging protectedVirtualPath="~/EPiServer/" protectedPath="\\location\Modules\_Protected" publicVirtualPath="~/modules/" publicPath="modules" />

<virtualPathProviders>
  <clear />
  <add name="ProtectedModules" virtualPath="~/EPiServer/" physicalPath="\\location\Modules\_Protected" type="EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathNonUnifiedProvider, EPiServer.Framework" />
</virtualPathProviders>
```

I have restarted IIS as well but still website tries to access EPiServer.Cms.Shell.UI.zip from old location which is [websiterootfolder]\modules_protected\CMS

Can anyone please help????

Comment: What's your base path as configured by `<appData basePath="your root path" />` in web.config?

Comment: I would not recommend to move the protected folder, I would recommend to have it checked in instead, doing like that, everyone will get updates when they run get latest from the source control.

As Ted is saying, you can move your appData path and by that share your blobs and so, just look for the string he says in the comment.